# How to partition a fully used hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, fedora

I installed Ubuntu on my laptop which when I got it I had Fedora 13 installed on it as the OS. Now I want to install Fedora 18 in a dual boot with Ubuntu. Problem is when I installed Ubuntu, I didn't partition for dual boot and I gave the entire hard drive to Ubuntu and no longer have the space to dual boot. How can I lower the partition on Ubuntu to make space on the hard drive for Fedora? I want to split the hard drive 50/50 between the two.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using [Gparted](http://gparted.org/). 
Boot from a live ubuntu cd or usb. Open `gparted` (it's pre-installed in live cd or usb).
Select the partition on which you have installed Ubuntu. Right click and select option **Resize/Move**. Then you can shrink the partition as per your need. 
This will create an `unallocated space`. Create new partition of it.
Now you can install `Fedora 18` on it.